# How can I get the ability to climb walls, if the Slumbering Sanctuary itself requires climbing walls to reach it?

Tags: dead-cells

In *Dead Cells*, I'm trying to get the Spider Rune in order to climb walls. However, [I heard that it is in the Slumbering Sanctuary](https://deadcells.fandom.com/wiki/Runes_and_Upgrades#Spider_Rune). I set out to look for the Slumbering Sanctuary and it, itself, requires the ability to climb walls. I'm very confused.

How can I get the ability to climb walls?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Most of the areas in Dead Cells can be accessed from multiple areas.  In this case, you've hit the entrance that requires the Spider Rune.  You'll need to go through a different sequence.  Looking at the [Biome Map](https://deadcells.fandom.com/wiki/Biomes_Map), it looks like you'll need to go through the Toxic and Ancient Sewers, which do require other runes, the Vine and Ram (ground-pound) abilities.