# How do I climb tall vertical shafts?

Tags: dead-cells

I keep running into tall vertical shafts that I can't get past. There aren't any plant vines I can grow to climb up. How do I get up these shafts? Is there a wall jump upgrade I'm missing?

[image: Tall vertical shaft]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're missing the Spider Rune. You can obtain it in the Slumbering Sanctuary. If you wonder how to get there, see [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/400287/how-can-i-get-the-ability-to-climb-walls-if-the-slumbering-sanctuary-itself-req).

Comment: Wondering if this now becomes a dupe of that question